# Concordion NUnit throws NullReferenceException when discovering test

Tags: .net, concordion

I'm new to Concordion and just started trying it out.

I downloaded their example "Kickstart" project at https://github.com/concordion/concordion-net-kickstart/releases/tag/v1.2.0 and I also created my own project to get a better sense of how it works.

When I attempt to run my tests in both the Kickstart project and my own project that I created I encounter the same errors:

NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering tests is started
Exception System.NullReferenceException, Exception thrown discovering tests in C:\Users......\concordion-net-kickstart-1.2.0\Kickstart.Spec\bin\Debug\Kickstart.Spec.dll
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering test is finished

I'm not sure why this is happening or what's causing this as I ran their example project straight out of the box and even then it was tossing back the same exception as my own project that I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulation for your first Concordion.NET tests.

Unfortunately, there is an issue with the NUnit Test Adapter (https://github.com/nunit/nunit-vs-adapter/issues/9) that prevents loading of NUnit addins such as the one used to run Concordion.NET tests.

As described on the website of Concordion, there is a workaround to be able to run Concordion.NET tests with the NUnit Test Adapter:
http://concordion.org/dotnet/RunningTests.html#test-adapter

You can use another NUnit client to run Concordion.NET tests:

- ReSharper: http://concordion.org/dotnet/RunningTests.html#resharper
- TestDriven.NET: http://concordion.org/dotnet/RunningTests.html#testdriven.net
- NUnit GUI Runner: http://concordion.org/dotnet/RunningTests.html#stand-alone

I hope you enjoy Concordion.NET.
Please, don't hesitate to ask any further questions.

Comment: if you enjoy Concordion, like it on facebook: https://www.facebook.com/concordion